# How to check in JavaScript if table row with specific index exist?

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript block code:

```
var trows = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows;  
for(var j = ((pageNumber - 1) * rowsPerPage); j < ((pageNumber) * rowsPerPage); j++)
{
  trows[j].style.display = 'table-row';
}
```

Before I implement this row:

```
 trows[j].style.display = 'table-row';
```

I need to check if table row with scpecific index exists.

How to check in JavaScript if table row with specific index exist?

Comment: Is jQuery an option?

Comment: trows[j].value != undefined

Comment: No I don't use jQuery

Answer (score 5):

Since `undefined` is falsey, you can just do this:

```
if (trows[j]) {
    trows[j].style.display = 'table-row';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(typeof trows[j] !== 'undefined') {
    trows[j].style.display = 'table-row';
}
```

You can check if the type is undefined.